# why not exist nginx module with rtsp?

Tags: nginx, module, rtsp, rtmp

I am new with video knowledge, and i have searched several articles about it.
Now i know `rtsp` protocol is for use in entertainment and communications systems to control streaming media servers, and `rtmp` is similar like it but for flash client.

My question is there is a great module named `nginx-rtmp-module` with `nginx`, but not a module `rtsp` with `nginx`. Dose anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange question, there are severals protocols for media communications, RTMP/RTMFP, RTSP, HLS, HDS, MPEG-DASH... and I imagine that the guy/team who has built nginx-rtmp-module has not enough time to implement all of them!

If you are searching for a media server working with both RTSP and RTMP there are Wowza, Red5 (with plugin) and MonaServer (only a beta version of RTSP) for example.